# $l-\infty$ norm minimization

Tags: analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose I want to minimize $||Ax-b||_{\infty}$, where $A$ and $b$ are given. Can I say anything about the $||x^*||_2$, that is about the $l_2$ norm of the minimizer?

Comment: What would you like to say?

Comment: Hopefully bound it in terms of some norms of A and b